# Is there a good alternative to Google Analytics that does not sample?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, pageviews

I want to pay my writers based on unique page views. Right now I am getting my data from Google Analytics. The frustrating thing is that the numbers given by Google Analytics are from sampling.

So is there a Analytics Service to get unique page views that does not sample its data?

Or as anyone try doing something similar to what I am trying to accomplish, what would you recommend I do?

Comment: Make your requests smaller and the data wont sample, or pay for a professional Google analytics account and you can use unsampled reports.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Unsampler](http://www.unsampler.io)

Extract unsampled data from a Google Analytics Standard profile. Avoid sampling and get at your real data.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use PIWIK - it is server side analytics system, but you will must save all data on your server - you need separate mysql data base.
[image]